# error in saving data to SQliteDataBase

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have a app which Saves Contacts to a SQlite Database.

I Have a Database.java class . which is this :

```
    package digicare.phonebook;

    import android.R;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.ContentValues;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.database.SQLException;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View.OnCreateContextMenuListener;

    public class Database {


private static final String DATABSE_NAME ="MY_DB";
private static final String DATABSE_TABLE ="MY_TABLE";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION=1;


public static final String KEY_ID = "ID" ;
public static final String  PHONE_NUM ="NUMBER";
public static final String PERSON_NAME="NAME";

public static final String DATABASE_CREATE =" CREATE TABLE "+ DATABSE_TABLE+ "(" + 
                                             KEY_ID    + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENTs" + 
                                             PHONE_NUM + "TEXT NOT NULL"+ 
                                             PERSON_NAME+"TEXT NOT NULL )" ;


private DatabaseHelper myHelper;

private final Context mycontext;
private SQLiteDatabase myDB;


private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABSE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);

    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+ DATABSE_TABLE );
        onCreate(db);
    }

}

public Database(Context c){
    mycontext=c;
}
public Database open() throws SQLException {

    myHelper=new DatabaseHelper(mycontext);
    myDB= myHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this ;
    }
public void close(){
    myHelper.close();
}
public long createEntry(String number, String name) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues() ;
    cv.put(PERSON_NAME, name);
    cv.put(PHONE_NUM,number);
    return myDB.insert(DATABSE_TABLE, null, cv);
}
    }
```

From the other class (which extends the Activity) i called the createEntry() methode :

```
    Boolean diditwork=true;
                    try{
                    Database entry = new Database(Main_Activity.this);
                    entry.open();
                    entry.createEntry(number , name);

                    entry.close();
                    }catch(Exception e ){
                        diditwork=false;
                    }finally{
                        if (diditwork){
                            Dialog d = new Dialog(getApplicationContext());
                            d.setTitle("Ring Manager");
                            TextView tv = new TextView(getApplicationContext()) ;
                            tv.setText("Saved");
                            d.setContentView(tv);
                            d.show();

                        }
                    }
```

But i have a problems the logcat shows error .. that " No such table: MY_TABLE "

How to solve this problem?
Am i have to call the onCreate(db) method?

Or what to do?

Answer (score 1):

You should change the keyword AUTOINCREMENTs to AUTOINCREMENT. You have an extra s. Also, you should leave a space between the column name and its declaration. I think this is preventing the table from being created.

Comment: When i call the createEnrty() method then the onCreate(db) in automatically called ???

Comment: on the DATABASE_CREATE String definition.